# Calculate distance between alphabets in a word in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset "sc" with alphabets and with coordinates. For example,

```
alphabets   Y   X
q           3   1
w           3   2
e           3   3
r           3   4
t           3   5
y           3   6
u           3   7
i           3   8
o           3   9
...
```

I am interested to calculate the distance between consecutive alphabets in a word using Pythagoras' theorem.
for example, for the word 'que' is distance will be (6 + 4) = 10.

I have written a code in python but my code is taking almost 2 hours to run. I have a dataset with more than 500k rows.
P. S. The word can be alphanumeric.

Here is my code:

```
def key_score(w):
    score=0
    for i in range(0,len(w)-1):
        t=pd.DataFrame(list(w[i:i+2].lower()))
        t.columns = ['alphabets']
        u = pd.merge(sc, t, how='inner', on=['alphabets'])
        v = np.sqrt(((u['X'][0] - u['X'][1])**2)+((u['Y'][0] - u['Y'][1])**2))
        score = score + v
    return score
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: One place to start might be the built-in spatial distance metrics in [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/spatial.distance.html#module-scipy.spatial.distance), bound to be faster than writing them from scratch

Comment: the example distance equation you give (for "que") is not equivalent to the equation in your code (`v = np.sqrt(...)`).  can you please update the expected output of this equation for consistency?

Comment: can you explain what you're doing with the `t=...` assignment?  (in particular, what are you indexing with `w[i:i+2]` and why?)

Comment: @andrew_reece the out given here (that is 10 for the word 'que') is what I am expecting. And the code is also giving me the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = df.set_index('alphabet') #if alphabet is not in index
word = 'que'
np.sqrt(df.reindex([*word]).diff().abs().sum().pow(2).sum())
```

Output:

```
10
```

Comment: I have tried this one. It is also very slow. It is still runny from past 40 minutes